# DOMElement::setAttribute добавить в атрибут спецсимволы (${})

Tags: php

Нужно добавить ссылке атрибут href с содержимым ${CONTENT}.
Делаю так

```
$link->setAttribute(href, "${CONTENT}");
```

На выходе получаю примерно следующее href="%24%7BCONTENT%7D".
Как добавить в атрибут символы без изменений без url_encode, может быть как-то экранировать?

Comment: это явно кусок  какого то фреймворка, или чего то самописного, не думаю что кто нибудь обладает ТАКИМИ навыками ясновидения что бы определить в чем ошибка по этой строчке кода, опишите проблему более подробно, что у вас  содержится в ${CONTENT} что происходить в $link->setAttribute, что вы делаете, зачем почему..

Comment: Проблема в DOMElement::setAttribute, нужно записать строку как она есть "${CONTENT}", без изменений без url_encode. Вопрос по функционалу DOMElement